# Get all unique licenses from multiple packages and sort using bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I am working on a project that is about to be released soon. We have 13 different packages. I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/license-checker. I want to integrate this to my build so every time that i build for production my shell script should run and produce all licenses in all packages that i have. There are different types of licenses out there.. Example MIT, BSD etc and many more.

In our website we will display all licenses in their own license type category so sorting them is crucial.

What i have right now is a bash script that does the following:

```
//licensecollector.sh
for d in ../packages/*/ ; do
    license-checker >> licenses.txt
done
```

This produces a file with results looking like this:

```
├─ abbrev@1.1.1
│  ├─ licenses: ISC
│  ├─ repository: https://github.com/isaacs/abbrev-js
│  ├─ publisher: Isaac Z. Schlueter
│  ├─ email: i@izs.me
│  ├─ path: 
│  └─ licenseFile: 
├─ ansi-styles@3.2.1
│  ├─ licenses: MIT
│  ├─ repository: https://github.com/chalk/ansi-styles
│  ├─ publisher: Sindre Sorhus
│  ├─ email: sindresorhus@gmail.com
│  ├─ url: sindresorhus.com
│  ├─ path: 
│  └─ licenseFile: 
├─ array-find-index@1.0.2
│  ├─ licenses: MIT
│  ├─ repository: https://github.com/sindresorhus/array-find-index
│  ├─ publisher: Sindre Sorhus
│  ├─ email: sindresorhus@gmail.com
│  ├─ url: sindresorhus.com
│  ├─ path: 
│  └─ licenseFile:
```

Keep in mind i have never done bash scripting before.
This seems to get all my licenses to one file (correct me if i am wrong).

Now all that seems to be left to do is to sort these licenses into their categories which i have no clue on how to do. Any ideas?

Comment: https://medium.com/@fokusman/the-easiest-way-to-check-all-your-npm-dependency-licenses-753075ef1d9d

Comment: It'll be much easier to parse the output of `licence-checker` if you add the option `--csv` or `--json`.